# Gerrit 2.11 with gitlab replication is not working: push not permitted

Tags: git, gitlab, gerrit

everyone:

I have tried to enable Gerrit git-replication feature to sync with my Gitlab server, but I met some errors as below:

http://pastebin.com/ufUX5cLb

---

And here is my gerrit git-replication configuration:

> [remote "gitlab"]
>     projects = novadocker
>     url = git@10.10.10.1:jhyang/${name}.git
>     push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* 
>     push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
>     push = +refs/changes/*:refs/changes/*
>     threads = 3

My project on gitlab-server is all default setup.

Anyone has solutions to help me ? thanks :p

Comment: The error message is full of HTML and is completely unreadable. Please clean it up.

Comment: okay, i move them in my pastebin http://pastebin.com/ufUX5cLb

Comment: Did you grant the gerrit user Developer/Master/Owner permission to this repository in gitlab? Is the branch protected?  See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/permissions/permissions.md for permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a cron job in the repository with the following commands:

```
cd </path/to/target/repo>
git remote update
```

Make sure you have a config on your target repo with the ff:

```
[remote "origin"]
url=<target repo>
fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
mirror = true
```